# How to get column title from SP list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

Getting list items from my SP online list is not a problem, but I am trying to get the column title.
I have a column called Name and would like to get the title so it appears above list items.

Javascript.

Comment: In c# or javascript?

Comment: I am using Javascript.

Comment: you mean 'Name' is the internal name of the column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you send a GET to following URL, it should return you items with column name

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/items
```

And following URL should return column display and internal names

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/Fields?$select=Title,InternalName
```

Learn more about rest [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)